# How to send state data to a node file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server, state

I've created a little React/Node app and I want to send a certain piece of data from the React frontend to the Node backend. The data is based on what you type in an input and saved as a state `inputCardHolder`, I want to now send that data to the other file, which is non-React, to be used there.
How would I do this?

**App.js(React)**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [cardHolder, setCardHolder] = useState("");
  const [inputCardHolder, setinputCardHolder] = useState("");// This is the state I wanna send
  const [cardNumber, setCardNumber] = useState("");
  const [balance, setBalance] = useState("");
  const [expDate, setExpDate] = useState("");
  const [cvc, setCvc] = useState("");

  function getCardData() {
    axios.get("http://localhost:5000/", { crossdomain: true })
      .then(response => {
        setCardHolder(response.data.data.name_on_card);
        setCardNumber(response.data.data.card_pan);
        setBalance(response.data.data.amount + "  " + response.data.data.currency);
        setExpDate(response.data.data.expiration);
        setCvc(response.data.data.cvv);
      })
  };

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    setinputCardHolder(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className='vcard'>
        <div className='theBalance'>
          <h2>{balance}</h2>
        </div>
        <div className='numNcvc'>
          <h2 className='theNum'>{cardNumber}</h2>
          <h2 className='theCvc'>{cvc}</h2>
        </div>
        <div className='expNholder'>
          <h2>Expiry Date<br/> {expDate}</h2>
          <h2>Card Holder<br/> {inputCardHolder}</h2>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className='details-div'>
        <form className='details'>
          <input 
            placeholder='Name on Card' 
            type="text" 
            id='cardholder'
            name='cardholder'
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            value={inputCardHolder}></input>
          <input placeholder='Amount (in USD)' type="text"></input>
          <input placeholder='MTN MoMo Number' type="text"></input>
        </form>
        <button className='createCardBtn' onClick={getCardData}>
          Create Card
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**nodecard.js(Node Backend)**

```
const { response } = require('express');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const Flutterwave = require('flutterwave-node-v3');
const flw = new Flutterwave("FLWPUBK_TEST-63a79c5a6fe457d75a611b0f376e3e53-X", "FLWSECK_TEST-a6281194ef4ca095e794a1681fe32d69-X");

// Payload: Flutterwave Card Details
const payload = {
    "currency": "USD",
    "amount": 50,
    "billing_name": "Daniel Odd",// I need the 'inputCardHolder' data to be here
    "billing_address": "2014 Forest Hills Drive",
    "billing_city": "React",
    "billing_state": "NY",
    "billing_postal_code": "000009",
    "billing_country": "US",
}

flw.VirtualCard.create(payload)
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);

        app.use(function(req, res, next) {
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
            next();
          });

        app.get("/", (req, res) => {
            res.send(response)
        });
    });

/*const wordy = "Another word"

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    next();
  });

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send(wordy)
});*/

app.listen(5000, () => {console.log("Server started on port 5000")})

//createVcard();
```

Comment: If you want to send some data to server then you should use `Post` not `Get` request...

Comment: `Post` where? The frontend or backend? So I should be using `axios.post`?

Comment: Yeah you should use axios.post ... There are plenty examples out there .... Just a search away

Comment: Yu, thanks. This ended up helping a lot